# Invoking Custom controller method after successful save?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Working on a VF page where I am inserting a Contact record. I have created a extension controller to insert a custom object record after this Save action completes. But I am not able to get this action. Here is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactCreationCtrl">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Create Contact">

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.AccountId}" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" oncomplete="createSampleObjRecord()" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class ContactCreationCtrl {
public Contact newCon {get;set;}

public ContactCreationCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController con){
    newCon = (Contact)con.getRecord();
}

public void createSampleObjRecord(){

    Contact currentCon = [Select FirstName, AccountId From Contact Where Id =: newCon.Id];
    //Insert New record
  }
}
```

The custom controller's method is never getting executed. Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the contact in extension itself without using the standard save functionality. i.e. by directly calling your method from `commandButton`. For this, you will have to make below changes

Visualforce page : Call your method directly from save button

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!createSampleObjRecord}" value="Save"/>
```

Controller : Insert contact in your custom method

```
public void createSampleObjRecord(){
    insert newCon;
    Contact currentCon = [Select FirstName, AccountId From Contact Where Id =: newCon.Id];
    //Insert New record
}
```

Comment: I have tried actionFuncion approach, but that doesn't seemed to be working.

Comment: NVM, I have tried the 2nd approach and it worked. Thanks

Comment: That's great ! Updated the answer i.e. removed first approach as `actionFunction` doesn't seem to work as expected when using standard save action.

Answer (score -1):

The oncomplete attribute is trying to call a nonexistent JavaScript function. In your Apex controller, you'll need to implement the save method and call your createSampleObjRecord method from there